# Is this consider an independent clause?

Tags: grammar, independent-clauses

> First, to harbingers of doom. One is the upheaval in the market for “speculative grade” (or junk) bonds.

The first sentence seems to be grammatically incorrect. The subject does not have any predicate. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: It's not formally correct, but the meaning is clear; 'First, [we turn our attention] to...'

Comment: It’s a form of address. or an introductory phrase.

Comment: It's an independent clause if you consider parts of it to have been omitted but assumed. It's like asking if *Yes* is a sentence, when there is only a single word. And note that even if something isn't an independent clause, that does not mean it's ungrammatical.

Comment: It's traditional rhetoric, like the beginning of the Aeneid: _I sing of arms and the man_. There's an unspoken (but clearly demonstrated) performative _I speak_ to be understood right before _to harbingers of doom_.

Comment: Interesting so is silent (I speak), is there any grammar sources I can refer to?